# Serial Port Data Structure

Tags: macos, hardware, serial-port, hardware-interface

I need to send data to a hardware device over serial port. I'm using a program called serial port tool for os x.

After I connect to the device there is a form box where I can type data to send. I have no idea how to format the data.

Here is an excerpt from the manual for the device.

"The Net Manager Command structure consists of one start byte, one command byte, five bytes of data, and a one byte checksum.  Each message packet is formatted as follows:"

an example command is: 
Byte0=30 Byte1=7 Byte2=5 Byte3=1 Byte4=2 Byte5=0 Byte6=245

How do I type that into the form box in serial port tool?

Thanks,
Seth

Comment: You could use Slip or SlipMux, for more details please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467950/sending-packets-over-serial-comms-java/41823403#41823403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the "serial port tool" you're using come with any documentation?

Assuming the "form box" is expecting printable characters, what you're looking for is a way to input an arbitrary byte value. For example, there might be a mechanism that lets you use an octal or hexadecimal escape sequence (such as \036 or \24).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The program was actually called "Serial Port Tool." I switched to a windows PC and found a better program that let me select the format I wanted to enter data in (decimal, hex etc...).