# mqtt serial message without ethernet

Tags: arduino, mqtt

everywhere I look, if it comes to MQTT messaging, it is all over Ethernet.  Unfortunately, I do not have Ethernet wires available.

I am automating my home, wanting to use mqtt as messaging service.  My buttons give a signal (like light 'on') to an arduino board running a mqtt client.  How do i put out the mqtt message on the serial lines so the transmitted message can be straight forwardly be picked up by an mqtt broker, without using the ethernet cables?

Comment: What sort of wiring do you have in your house? Are you using RS-232/RS-485? Full or half-duplex?

Comment: it is all EIB, 4 wires

Comment: I believe there is a variant of mqtt for serial, but it may be simpler to get what mqtt needs which is a tcp connection running over serial using e.g.  Ppp or as njh says using slip. Of course you will need to bring all your arduino connections to your mqtt broker so will need hardware with multiple serial ports, might be cheaper to buy an ethernet switch and use ethernet. Or can you put your arduino on wifi?

Comment: Avoid the wiring issues completely, use a NodeMCU with wifi?

Answer (score 11):

As I was looking for the same answer and didn't find anything to my liking, I decided to write an implementation that enables any Bluetooth, USB or pure serial port communication to send MQTT message. You can find the result here : https://github.com/vortex314/serial2mqtt
It enables any linux machine ( Raspberry Pi 1, Raspi 3 , PC ) to act as a gateway.
It's written in C++ so should be lightweight enough for small devices.
Hope this helps.

Update 27/6 : build folder contains pre-build version for Linux Intel and Raspberry.

Answer (score 4):

I am trying to achieve similar goals for my house automation, although I do have Cat5e in the walls, so could use Ethernet.

Here are some possibilities for using MQTT over serial communication:

- Use SLIP between the Arduino and the gateway. The SerialIP client library which implements TCP/IP over serial: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SerialIP . Although I have not tested if this works with a MQTT client library. Nick O'Leary's MQTT Client theoretically works with any implementation of the Arduino 'Client' class.
- It may be possible to implement MQTT directly over serial, without TCP/IP, although I am not aware of any gateways to do this.
- MQTT-SN (a slightly different protocol to MQTT) was designed for sending messages over unreliable transport, and may be better suited to a serial line. If you are interested in publish-only, I wrote a **very** basic library to send MQTT-SN packets over serial: https://github.com/njh/DangerMinusOne
- You could use something like Node-RED on the Linux gateway, talking some other serial protocol (Firmata?) to the Arduino and then converting to MQTT using Node-RED.

I did start looking at MQTT over serial implementations but one of the problems I didn't resolve was how to deal with multiple devices:

- Adding lots of serial ports to Linux is complex/expensive (well sort of https://twitter.com/njh/status/570298977310150656)
- Reliable serial over longer distances requires extra components for RS-485
- MQTT doesn't work well over half-duplex, without an extra layer of software to deal with a master polling slaves for messages

So I am current looking at implementing MQTT-SN for the ENC28j60 ethernet controller...

Answer (score 0):

For SLIP there is also the backwards compatible SlipMux which could easily support MQTT packet types. See also: [sending packets over serial comms java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467950/sending-packets-over-serial-comms-java/41823403#41823403)

You could build a simple proxy that converts MQTT packets to SlipMux packets on one side and decodes the packets on the other side. The MQTT implementation should not notice anything.

Comment: the mqtt packets on 'the other side' are wall mounted arduino micro boards, which will not have the resource (read memory) to actully implement more than just basic serial communication

Comment: You do not need much more read memory. You just have to spend a tiny bit of CPU to replace escaped characters by the non escaped version. This might need a look ahead of 1 char. When using SlipMux instead of Slip you get one extra byte in the beginning of the message.

It's pretty good implementable in a stream like API.